# Schema to store data from two different tables in a single reference table SQL

Tags: sql

I have a power supply that requires a breaker. We have two types of breakers, standard and electronic. Because the structure of these breaker types are different they have to reside in separate tables.
What is the best practice for referencing the power supply to 1 of the breakers?

```
Breaker table 1
breakerStyleID | breakerName
1               Standard Breaker 1
2               Standard Breaker 2


Electronic Breaker table 1
breakerStyleID  ElecbreakerName
1               Electronic Breaker 1
2               Electronic Breaker 2
```

I want to save the breaker that is selected from one of the above tables and associate it with the Power supply.

```
Power supply Table
pid  breakerstyleID   ElecbreakerstyleID
1       1
2                           1
```

My assumption is that we have to have breaker IDs in the reference table and if one is null, use the other?

Comment: add DBMS system in which you implementing this stuff

Comment: Best practice is same table.

Comment: _Because the structure of these breaker types are different they have to reside in separate tables._
What is different about the two structures? Like @jarlh has mentioned, it feels like you could store the Breaker details in the same table and then you can just reference the Breaker for PowerSupply using the BreakerID which should be the primary key in the Breaker table. Also BreakerType could be a static enum table.

Comment: UNION ALL the tables.

Comment: The fields shown are the same type of info for both tables. Agree should probably be one Breakers table with another field to identify as Standard or Electric. Then the junction table has only one field for BreakerID.